# using template parameter to concat select path xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying a number of different ways to create a re-usable template but am having problems:

```
 <xsl:template name="translation">
    <xsl:param name="labelName"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('/Response/Localisation/',$labelName,'/.')"/>
 </xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="translation">
    <xsl:param name="labelName"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/Response/Localisation/$labelName/."/>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to use the template like so:

```
<xsl:call-template name="translation">
    <xsl:with-param name="labelName" select="ReportsSelection" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Basically when I call the template, I want to be given the value from my xml, in this case at location "Response/Localisation/ReportsSelection".

At the moment though I am being given the literal string version as opposed to the value from the xml.

I don't use xslt very often. Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly is the $labelName variable defined, **before** you use it to define the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
    <xsl:call-template name="translation">
        <xsl:with-param name="labelName" select="'ReportsSelection'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

With this:

```
<xsl:template name="translation">
    <xsl:param name="labelName"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/Response/Localisation/*[local-name()=$labelName]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Variable in path step doesn't seems to be allowed, but you can use the variable as literal string with the following trick :

```
<xsl:template name="translation">
    <xsl:param name="labelName"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/Response/Localisation/*[name()=$labelName]/."/>
</xsl:template>
```

The above xpath selector matches any element (`*`) and then filter the element by it's name against literal string provided by variable (`$labelName`)

Comment: Thanks for this. Just missed out though Kevin was that bit sooner ;)